# Power Apps Portal - Cannot create a blank app . Something went wrong and language dropdown is blank

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-portal

I am trying to create a new blank power app portal but as soon as I click on the create blank app button, it gives me a 'Something went wrong' error message. The create button next to the cancel button is grayed out and it is not clickable. What is causing this error and how can I fix this?

[image]

I tried creating canvas and model-driven app to test if I would get the same problem but these 2 are working so portal is the only one that is giving me this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you may have not created an environment before you started to create a Portal. Portals don't work on the default environment.

You need to go to the Power Platform admin center and then create an environment first https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/environments. You may need to select 'Trial' if you are just starting out.

Then go back to the maker portal again https://make.powerapps.com/ and on the top right corner change the environment from 'default' to the one you created just now.

Now try to create portal app again, it should be fine.